# google-visualization-errors: container is null. message: One or more participants failed to draw()

Tags: javascript, c#, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google dashboard in my web app but I am getting the following error.

> google-visualization-errors: container is null. message: One or more participants failed to draw()

My code is similar to what [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) code suggests but I'm still facing the error.

My JS (generated via C#)-

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart', 'controls']});

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

    function drawDashboard() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Status', 'Count'],
            ['Closed', 671],
            ['Resolved', 5],
            ['Test', 3]
        ]); //test///
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

      var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
            'containerId': 'filter_div',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnLabel': 'Count'
            }
        });

        var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'PieChart',
            'containerId': 'divIncidentStatus',
            'options': {
                'width': 300,
                'height': 300,
                'pieSliceText': 'value',
                'legend': 'right'
            }
        });

        dashboard.bind(slider, pieChart);
        dashboard.draw(data);

    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="dashboard_div">
                <div class="filter_div"></div>
                <div id="divIncidentStatus"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

P.S - I have tried calling the JS code before and after my HTML DIVs but nothing helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like a typo
need to set the `id` attribute, instead of `class`
on both `dashboard_div` and `filter_div`

instead of...

```
    <div class="dashboard_div">
      <div class="filter_div"></div>
      <div id="divIncidentStatus"></div>
    </div>
```

change to...

```
    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <div id="divIncidentStatus"></div>
    </div>
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'callback': function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Status', 'Count'],
      ['Closed', 671],
      ['Resolved', 5],
      ['Test', 3]
    ]);
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
    var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'filter_div',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Count'
      }
    });
    var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'PieChart',
      'containerId': 'divIncidentStatus',
      'options': {
        'width': 300,
        'height': 300,
        'pieSliceText': 'value',
        'legend': 'right'
      }
    });
    dashboard.bind(slider, pieChart);
    dashboard.draw(data);
  },
  'packages': ['corechart', 'controls']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <div id="divIncidentStatus"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the good 'ol basics problem ! Thanks a ton. I think I need to sleep now before coding more.